# InfluxDB not returning results when group by time offset at a summer/winter time change

Tags: timezone, influx-db

Let's start with an example. I've got an application that logs a point every minute. When I aggregate this data into a query where I'll have the count of logs per day, I get the following result. Keep in mind, that the query and the data is in UTC.

```sql
SELECT count(int_3) 
FROM data 
WHERE time >= '2023-10-26T00:00:00Z' 
AND time < '2023-10-31T23:59:59Z' 
GROUP BY time(1d) fill(none)
```

```
2023-10-26T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-27T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-28T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-29T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-30T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-31T00:00:00Z 1440
```

This is the expected, result. Also when I use a timezone in the query I get the expected result. Keep in mind that this query includes daylight saving, which results in one day having 1 bucket more.

```
SELECT count(int_3) 
FROM data 
WHERE time >= '2023-10-26T00:00:00+02:00' 
AND time < '2023-10-31T23:59:59+01:00' 
GROUP BY time(1d) fill(none) 
TZ('Europe/Amsterdam')
```

```
2023-10-26T00:00:00+02:00 1320
2023-10-27T00:00:00+02:00 1440
2023-10-28T00:00:00+02:00 1440
2023-10-29T00:00:00+02:00 1500
2023-10-30T00:00:00+01:00 1440
2023-10-31T00:00:00+01:00 1440
```

So far so good right. Let's focus on the issue I'm facing. When ever somebody want to move the start time of the query, in the example (2023-10-26T00:00:00Z), we need to add an offset to the `GROUP BY time()` clause, as InfluxDB normally start bucketing from the unixtimestamp 0.

According to their documentation page you can use a `offset_interval` to fix the start time of the query results

> The offset_interval is a duration literal. It shifts forward or back the InfluxDB database’s preset time boundaries. The offset_interval can be positive or negative.

For example let's use the first query (UTC) again and shift the start time and endtime one hour back.

```
SELECT count(int_3) 
FROM data 
WHERE time >= '2023-10-25T23:00:00Z' 
AND time < '2023-10-31T22:59:59Z' 
GROUP BY time(1d) fill(none)
```

Without using a offset_interval, the results are still timestamped on midnight.

```
2023-10-26T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-27T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-28T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-29T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-30T00:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-31T00:00:00Z 1380
```

Because the starttime of the query is `2023-10-25T23:00:00Z` I also want the results to reflect that. I need to use an offset of 23 hours (calculated with this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807316/5686835)

```
SELECT count(int_3) 
FROM data 
WHERE time >= '2023-10-25T23:00:00Z' 
AND time < '2023-10-31T22:59:59Z' 
GROUP BY time(1d,23h) fill(none)
```

```
2023-10-25T23:00:00Z 1380
2023-10-26T23:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-27T23:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-28T23:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-29T23:00:00Z 1440
2023-10-30T23:00:00Z 1440
```

Perfect, now with the Timezone I want.

```
SELECT count(int_3) 
FROM data 
WHERE time >= '2023-10-25T23:00:00+02:00' 
AND time < '2023-10-31T22:59:59+01:00' 
GROUP BY time(1d,23h) fill(none)
TZ('Europe/Amsterdam')
```

```
2023-10-25T23:00:00+02:00 1260
2023-10-26T23:00:00+02:00 1440
2023-10-27T23:00:00+02:00 1440
2023-10-28T23:00:00+02:00 1440
2023-10-29T23:00:00+01:00 1320
2023-10-30T23:00:00+01:00 1440
```

And there is the problem. `2023-10-29` should have one hour of point (60 points) more than the other days, but actually got 2 hours (120 points) less, which I find difficult to explain.

Does somebody have an explanation or a solution for this?

I'm using InfluxDB v1.8.10 and v1.11.1.